# Is there a way to hide rows x through y in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 20 rows.  I'd like to hide rows 6 through 18.  I've tried variations of `table tr:nthchild(n+6)`, but this operator seems to lack the stopping point variable - e.g. it applies to everything starting with row 6.

I could do it by, but it seems inelegant:

```
table tr:nthchild(6),
table tr:nthchild(7),
...
table tr:nthchild(18) {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with css only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following (sourced from https://gist.github.com/rondevera/167627) should achieve what you're after

```
table tr:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+18) {
  display:none
}
```